# Delphi - TClientDataSet - storing filter and indexes definitions

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need some help concerning `TClientDataSet` since after doing extensive research, I'm still confused about some features.

From what I so far understand, saving the `TClientDataSet` structure to a file, preserves only the `FieldDefs`. All other definitions such as `filters` and `indexes` are lost. So, I must recreate them after openning the `DataSet`, in order to that definitions take place.

I infere from this, that, if I want to store those definitions in disk (so they will available to the application as a whole and not only for a specific form), I must maintain a separate `DataSet`. Then, at runtime, I can recreate all definitions from that `DataSet`.

My question is: is there any other mechanism to store those definitions, other than the one mentioned above? A `TDataSetProvider` can do the trick?

I appologize for my ignorance and appreciate any enlightment about the subject.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the thing! I want to avoid the use of a database. It may sound a bit odd, but for my own reasons, I want that the application use `TClientDataSet` only. I think that `DataSet` has all the fetures my application may need.

Comment: There are many possibilities: 1- Regedit, 2-IniFiles, 3- Database, 4-Other DataSets. In this specific case I believe IniFiles is better

Comment: @matheus. So a `TDataSetProvider` should not resolve, right?

Comment: DataSetProvider is often used to retrieve data from TQuery.

Comment: @matheus. But it has the capability to store the `DataSet` definitions?

Comment: AFAIK. No, it doesn't has this capability.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46689/discussion-between-user2383818-and-matheus-freitas)

Comment: @user2383818: why don´t you just use the ObjectInspector and set those definitions during design time? Indexes and filter will be saved in the DFM file and stored inside the .exe as a resource. When you instantiate the Form or DataModule where you droped the `TClientDataset`, those properties will be reloaded and the dataset will be ready. Then you just have to load the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many possibilities to do what you want.

But, `TDataSetProvider` is not one of them.

It is possible to use:

- 1 [TRegistry](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry)
- 2 [TIniFiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile)
- 3 Persist it in database (not a good approach)
- 4 Another `DataSet`, as you mentioned.

Pick the easier and most realiable for you.
 
`TIniFile` is very often used to save definitions in many scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

When you save ClientDataSet it saves data structure, data, index definitions, parameters, delta-data etc. It saves only one filter definition though.

You can also save indesies and filters in Delphi code.

As mentioned Registry and IniFiles are possibilities too.